# Default redirect for Error 404

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect, default

I want to introduce a functionality in my ASP.net website that, whenever a request is received for an unknown URL on my domain, the user is redirected to my `error_404.htm` page in the root of the application.

For example, if the request is `http://www.mydomain.com/blahblahblah`

Then instead of returning the standard 404 error page, I want it to redirect the request to `http://www.mydomain.com/error_404.htm`

**Update**
IIS Version 7.5 and .NET Framework Version 4

**Update**
`/blah.aspx` redirects but `/blah` does not

Comment: Oh no, please don't. When I've got to the wrong URL, I want to know. I also want the chance to edit what is in my address bar in case I made a typo. Have the error page provide some useful information, but don't redirect.

Comment: Do not do this.  It's incredibly annoying.

Comment: What version of .net you running and IIS version?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This is how you configure a custom 404 error page for both ASP.NET and non-ASP.NET requests:

```
<configuration>

   <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="http404.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
         <remove statusCode="404"/>
         <error statusCode="404" path="/http404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

As others already pointed out, you should not use an HTTP redirection to send the user to the home page, this is not only confusing to users but also to machines (e.g. search engines). It is important to use the 404 status code and not a 3xx code.

You can achieve the desired functionality using meta refresh on HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Not Found</title>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/"/>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Not Found</h1>
   <p>Redirecting to Home...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup your code is working but      `<error statusCode="404" path="/http404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>'
 just shows a blank page insted of  my error page. However i fixed it with `<error statusCode="404" path="error.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>` . I know i am violating your 3xx HTTp code suggestion

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: According to http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors/error if you use the ExecuteURL responseMode the path must be "a server relative URL", that's why I used `/http404.aspx`, in your case try `/error.aspx`, or adjust if the application is not at the root.

Comment: I think i have a same problem i guess. Explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144777/asp-net-404-redirect-not-working

Comment: i could not understand is this approach seo friendly? How search engines know that this is 404 page? do we have to add 404 meta tag in page head ? So that search engines know that this resource is not found and they did not index this page?

Answer (score 4):

You can point your users to a custom 404 by including the `customErrors` section in your web.config.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

As others have stated in the comments above, sending users back to your homepage is going to be not only annoying but functionally confusing.

My advice would be to send the user to a page that gives them some information about what's happened and offers them a next step (browse other products, go back to your dashboard etc).

Comment: Are you sure that you've tried exactly this? Perhaps you had the mode set to RemoteOnly in which case it'll only serve the custom error page to remote users. (i.e. not for you locally).

Comment: I suspect /blah.aspx redirects but /blah does not, @Shekhar_Pro can you confirm this?

Comment: @Rippo yeah this is the case, thanx for pointing me to this. Still i want to know if it is bbfb not bbfb.aspx

Comment: ok so answer my comment in your post regarding iis version and .net version.

Answer (score 2):

In my case changing "ResponseRewrite" to "ResponseRedirect" worked:

My MVC Webconfig file Configuration:

```
   <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/Login" />
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me. I just include this code between the tag `<system.webServer>` :

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/Erro/PaginaNaoEncontrada.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's already a part of the accepted answer. Is there anything new you want to tell us?

Comment: It's subtly different: Why the tilde? (Does that even work in httpErrors?)