# 404 Redirecting for non aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, error-handling

I am using the web.config code below to redirect requests to missing pages to a 404 error handling page:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="404.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

It works fine when I look for pages such as "missing.aspx" but it does not work for pages without the ".aspx" extension such as "missing.asp" or just "missing". When it does not work, it just loads a standard IIS 7.5 error page.

What am I doing wrong? I am using .net 4. I noticed other people asking the same question but they didn't get an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: try removing `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`

Comment: I tried using the information in this question but was not able to get it going. Would you be so kind to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798775/web-config-not-forwarding-to-404-error-page-on-non-aspx-pages

Comment: This worked for me I have a website Project https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661494/6665876

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [dbaseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001985/dbaseman) states this is because the asp.net handlers are not called for non-asp.net files. An easy way to force the asp.net handler to operate on all requests is to set the following in your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</system.webServer>
```

This tells IIS to run through all of the managed modules for all requests such as .html, .jpg, .css, .js, etc. This is typically frowned upon as it just introduces extra processing and latency.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Another option to try (cleaner than the above) was posted as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661699/701062

Comment: I tried using what you wrote but could not make it work. would you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798775/web-config-not-forwarding-to-404-error-page-on-non-aspx-pages

Comment: I love you... so much Gary S.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that non-ASPX extensions never make it to the ASP.NET handler; those errors you see are coming from IIS.  There is a separate section **httpErrors** under **system.webServer** in web.config that you will need to configure to handle these errors.  See [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors) for more info.

*Example from the link:*

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added the code below but now instead of running the error handling page, it displays the source code of the page (when attempting to load an non existent non aspx page).
`<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="404.aspx" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>`

Comment: This is the better answer as it does not rely on sending all request through the ASP.NET pipeline.  @Osprey - this is because of the errorMode being set to "DetailedLocalOnly"  This setting says, hey, if the request comes from the machine hosting the files, give some detailed info, else, show the 500 page I have defined.  This is useful in debugging scenarios.  You can change this setting to "Custom" and it will always display the friendly error message.

Comment: This does not work. And why did you add for 505 when the question was specifically about the 404 error?

Comment: @JGallardo doesn't work locally, but should work on the server.  I assume you can find/replace "404", or is that too much for you?

Comment: @McGarnagle I obviously replaced with 404. And then I added it to the remote server but still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the Web.config:

```html
<system.webServer>    
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Default.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

I took Osprey's code, and added responseMode="Redirect" to fix the problem of just displaying the source code of the page.