# How to add route to dynamic robots.txt in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, robots.txt

I have a robots.txt that is not static but generated dynamically. My problem is creating a route from root/robots.txt to my controller action.

This **works**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Robots",
url: "robots",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Robots" });
```

This **doesn't work**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Robots",
 url: "robots.txt", /* this is the only thing I've changed */
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Robots" });
```

The ".txt" causes ASP to barf apparently

Answer (score 14):

You need to add the following to your web.config file to allow the route with a file extension to execute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ...Omitted -->
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- ...Omitted -->
    <handlers>
      <!-- ...Omitted -->
      <add name="RobotsText" 
           path="robots.txt" 
           verb="GET" 
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See my blog post on [Dynamically Generating Robots.txt Using ASP.NET MVC](http://rehansaeed.com/dynamically-generating-robots-txt-using-asp-net-mvc/) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Answer here: [url with extension not getting handled by routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084024/url-with-extension-not-getting-handled-by-routing). Basically, when asp sees the "." it calls the static file handler, so the dynamic route is never used. The web.config files needs to be modified so /robots.txt will not be intercepted by the static file handler.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Rehan Saeed's `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` approach in web.config approach did not work for me due to the environment I was working in, resulting in 500 errors.

An alternative of using a web.config url rewrite rule worked for me instead:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Dynamic robots.txt" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="robots.txt" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/DynamicFiles/RobotsTxt" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```