# How can I manage robots.txt in Azure app service with a staging slot

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

I have an ASP.NET MVC app running in an Azure app service with one staging slot, and a build and release pipeline in `VSTS`.

I want the production instance to have `Allow /` in robots.txt and `Disallow /` in the staging slot at all times.

Currently we are changing robots.txt manually every time we do a swap but this is error prone

> How can I automate this process?

To solve this problem I did consider creating the robots.txt file dynamically based on app settings set in the Azure portal (set to stay with the slot), however this won't work since after the swap happens prod will have the staging `Disallow` rule.

Can anyone advise the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Robots are mainly used by search engines to crawl and check pages on the public websites. Staging and other deployment slots are not public (and should not be public — unless you have a good reason for that), and thus it doesn't make much sense to configure and manage it. Secondly, in most cases I would **recommend** to redirect any *public* request to your production slot and keep staging offline and active for internal use cases only. This would also help you to manage the analytics and logs coming from the public only, and not being polluted with internal and deployment slots stuff.

Anyways, if you are still inclined to do this, then there is one way that you can manage this. Write your own routing to control the robots file, and then render a `content-type: text/plain` page, which would be dynamic based on whether it is a staging or production request. Something like this,

```
// Create the robots.txt file dynamically, by controlling the URL handler
[Route("robots.txt")]
public ContentResult DynamicRobotsFile()
{
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    content.AppendLine("user-agent: *");

    // Check the condition by URL or Environment variable
    if(allow) {
        content.AppendLine("Allow: /");
    else {
        content.AppendLine("Disallow: /");
    }

    return this.Content(stringBuilder.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

This way you can manage how the robots.txt is created and you would be able to control the allow disallow for the robots. You can create a separate controller or an action only in the home controller of your app.

Now that you know how to do, you can setup the environment variables for the production/staging slots to check other requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where should this routing go? I tried putting this in a test app on `HomeController` and setting a breakpoint but it isn't being hit when I browse to `localhost:8888/robots.txt`. 

Can you help me understand why?

Comment: If you're using the older ASP.NET MVC, then you would need to configure this routing within the web.config file as well, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160744/how-to-add-route-to-dynamic-robots-txt-in-asp-net-mvc.

Answer (score 1):

I use below code and It works for me

```
[Route("robots.txt")]
public ContentResult DynamicRobotsFile()
{
     StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

     if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["production"] != "true")
     {
         content.AppendLine("user-agent: *");
         content.AppendLine("Disallow: /");
     }

    return this.Content(content.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

web.config

```
  <appSettings>    
      <add key="production" value="false" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="RobotsTxt" path="robots.txt" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
     </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

EDITED
I use this version now.

```
[Route("/robots.txt")]
public ContentResult RobotsTxt()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder().AppendLine("User-Agent: *");

    if (_env.IsProduction())
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Allow: /");

        sb.AppendLine("Disallow: /admin");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Disallow: /");
    }

    sb.AppendLine(string.Empty);
    sb.AppendLine($"Sitemap: {this.Request.Scheme}://{this.Request.Host}/sitemap.xml");

    return this.Content(sb.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

and I use IWebHostEnvironment to detect prod or not

```
public class SeoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;


    public SeoController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to add a setting for the production name, we can already get the environment dynamiclly using Hosting extensions

Comment: I updated answer for NET 6.0 MVC