# Routing a fake page name to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

For some pages on my site, such as the login page, I'd rather the user sees `login.htm`, rather than `/Home/Login`.

I've tried creating a route such as this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LoginScreen",
    url: "login.htm",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When ever I try to visit /login.htm, I get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers on here for routing a static page to a controller (eg. [url with extension not getting handled by routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084024/url-with-extension-not-getting-handled-by-routing)), but I would ask why you want to do this?

The user generally doesn't care about the url they are visiting and by doing this, you're actually moving away from one of the benefits of mvc, which is extensionless routing

**UPDATED**

Take a look at Url Rewriting in IIS (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)

You'll either going to have to capture all requests for .htm(l) pages and have some logic to figure out where to send them, or you'll have an individual rewrite rule for every .htm(l) page you want to map to a controller action

Comment: We want to do it for aesthetic reasons; i.e. we prefer to see .htm in some of our Uri's.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a couple of possible ideas. Personally, I would say that this is a less than ideal approach and that you're going to give yourself a maintenance headache, but it's definitely possible to do

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no other routes above `LoginScreen` and the controller and action names are correct then this should work fine.

If you do have other routing maps, comment them out and try it again.  It maybe that another route is interfering with it.