# ASP.Net 404 Redirect for friendly url not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have the below code to do 404 redirect in Global.asax.cs

```
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        if ((ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode()==404 ))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Custom404Page.aspx");
        }
    }
```

It works fine in visual studio and getting user friendly Custom404Page.

But when I deploy the same in IIS 7.0, it is not at all working. Shows the below message

[image]

In web.config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" />
```

Due to some reason we are asked not to put any entries in web.config for `statusCode="404"`. So we did in global.asax.cs

Why it is not working in IIS.

**UPDATE:** `domain/blahblah` is not showing Custom404Page. But `domain.blahblah.aspx`, shows Custom404Page.aspx. How to make it work with SEO friendly url `domain/blahblah`

Comment: Try doing a remote debugging and see if it's really hitting the Application_Error event.

Comment: Tips from this article helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483849/default-redirect-for-error-404