# MVC Simple Error Handle BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried many method, but still fail to make it.
Just want to show a 404/500 when the request is invalid.

Eg. There have no User Id = 100, if someone make this request, it should return 404. On the other hand, Throw 500, if server error happened.

I want this behavior to apply entire apps.

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int Id)
    {
        var db = new UserDbContext();
        var usr = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (usr == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User not found");
        return View(usr);
    }
```

with webconfig in system.web

```
<customErrors mode="On"  redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/General">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/BadRequest" />
</customErrors>
```

and in system.webserver

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
```

Tried many combination way, cannot make it work.
The result i get is a empty page, then browser console showing the 404/500 error. But I want it to show on page.

Someone could please point out my mistake. Thanks

Comment: Check if it's because of the web.config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483849/default-redirect-for-error-404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

or

```
return HttpNotFound();
```

or return error view form shared folder

```
return View("NotFound");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int Id)
    {
        var db = new UserDbContext();
        var usr = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (usr == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User not found");
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return View(usr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throw/return HTTP Exceptions like this:

`throw new HttpException(404, "Some description");`.

Or `return new HttpNotFoundResult("optional description");` for ASP.NET MVC 3 and above.

Or `return HttpNotFound("I did not find message goes here");` for MVC 4 and above.

Comment: I like the code you show, but the result is same, the white blank window, and console printe 404 not found. I was thinking, must be something wrong on my config. But I dont know where.

Comment: @EricK.Watch the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553922/custom-asp-net-mvc-404-error-page