# ASP C# Website Error Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using  error handling in Web.config and in Index.aspx i am using try and catch error handling. How do i catch error in Index.aspx catch { } based on  in Web.config.

Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
<error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Index.aspx

```
try {

}
catch {
How to trigger error handling in custom error?
}
```

Comment: I assume you just want to redirect to "error.aspx" in the catch? If so couldn't you just do Response.Redirect("Error.aspx")? Though your question is a bit unclear maybe you could explain exactly what you are trying to do in the catch?

Comment: In the catch { } i want to catch the error and automatically display the error page based on the error code in <customErrors>

Comment: You are going to have to write some code. This is not something that happens automatically by wrapping your logic in a try and catch or adding a few lines of config. Here the web config 404 are explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483849/default-redirect-for-error-404

Answer (score 0):

`defaultRedirect = "Error.aspx"` means that when you have an unhandled exception, ASP.NET will call your Error.aspx page instead of the standard one (called "Yellow Screen Of Death").

In my case I behave like this: first in `Global.asax` I store the unhandled exception in Application:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Try
        Application("errore") = Server.GetLastError
    Catch ex As Exception
    end try
End Sub
```

Then in the Handling page (in your case, Error.aspx) I do the Handling:

```
Partial Class Error
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            If Session("userid") <> "" Then
                'Ho avuto una eccezione vera !
                Dim ex As Exception = Application("errore")
                Application("errore") = Nothing
                If IsNothing(ex) Then
                    ex = Server.GetLastError()
                End If
                If Not IsNothing(ex) Then
                    Dim bex As Exception = ex.GetBaseException
                    If IsNothing(bex) Then
                        bex = ex
                    End If

                    'Show details of exception bex on page or store in DB

                    Catch exall As Exception

                    End Try
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```